# got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' when use decorator in django

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

i want to run decorator function before my view's dispatch method

below is my decorators.py

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def check_point(point=None):
  def decorator(view_func):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
      price = point or request.get_object().price
      if request.user.point.get_point() >= price:
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
  return decorator
```

and my view code

```
@method_decorator(check_point, name='dispatch')
class CheckWinningView(SingleObjectMixin, RedirectView):
  model = Product
```

But when I run the code, I get the following error:
[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

I know that 'pk' must be entered unconditionally due to the characteristics of singleobjectmixin.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *call* the `check_point` function when you decorate the function, so:

```
#            call check_point ↓
@method_decorator(check_point(), name='dispatch')
class CheckWinningView(SingleObjectMixin, RedirectView):
  model = Product
```

`call_checkpoint()` will then return the `decorator` function, and that will be applied as decorator on the method.

In order to decorate a class-based view, often a *mixin* is used instead of a decorator, for example the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to prevent people from seeing a page if they did not log in.